# PlatformNotSupportedException because of performance counters when calling a webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, performancecounter

I'm getting a PlatformNotSupportedException in Windows XP Home Edition (SP3) when calling a web service from a Winform application.

The stack trace is the following:

```
 System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Feature requires Windows 2000 or later.
    at System.Diagnostics.SharedUtils.CheckNtEnvironment()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize()
    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
    at System.Net.NetworkingPerfCounters.Initialize()
    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal..ctor(SettingsSection section)
    at System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal.get_Section()
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_DefaultMaximumResponseHeadersLength()
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri, ServicePoint servicePoint)
    at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Anyone has an idea what is going on ?
Thx

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Perhaps it's not supported on XP Home?

Comment: What is the actual code throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user had created a shortcut for starting the application, and had set the compatibility mode to Windows NT 4.

Turning the compatibility mode off solved the problem.